# Impossible to enter values via an input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I would like to enter a value into the input, but nothing happens. However, after 2 clicks the image is selected automatically.

[image]

I don't understand why I can't enter values in the input? I think it's an HTML/CSS problem?

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Thank you very much for your help and your time.

```css
ol.wrapper_digipass {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

.title_digipass {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.information_digipass {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.instruction_digipass {
  list-style: circle;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.logoDigipass {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
  width: 130px;
}

.logoDigipass img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -31px;
  left: -12px;
}

.logoDigipass1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.logoDigipass1 img {
  height: 125px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.wrapper_digipass {
  position: relative;
}

.section_instruction {
  margin-top: -60px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.width30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.width42 {
  width: 42%;
}

.width434 {
  width: 434px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="section_digipass">
  <ol class="wrapper_digipass">
    <li class="title_digipass">Utilisez votre digipass.</li>
    <p class="information_digipass">Après avoir réactivé votre digipass et introduit votre code PIN, celui-ci demande quelle application vous souhaitez utiliser.</p>
    <ul class="instruction_digipass">
      <li>Appuyez sur le chiffre "2"</li>
      <li>Introduisez d'abord les 6 <u>chiffres</u> soulignés extraits du code SVM du titre <u>000347075</u> , qui sont <strong>007075</strong></li>
      <li>Introduisez le nombre de titres de l'opération, donc 10, suivant le format : <strong>000010</strong></li>
      <li>Le digipass vous fournit un code de 6 chiffres à introduire dans la zone de confirmation</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="title_digipass">Introduisez le code de 6 chiffres affichés par le digipass.</li>
    <div class="wrapper_digipass">
      <div class="logoDigipass1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </div>
      <div class="section_instruction">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-form-label text-end width42">
            <label for="code">Code de confirmation</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 width434">
            <input type="text " id="code" name="code" class="form-control d-inline width30 "> et cliquez ensuite sur <strong>"Confirmer ".</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The problem doesn't occur with the code above. Please revise as necessary to demonstrate.

Comment: I will speculate, though, that you have an element overlaying your input. All those negative margins can be troublesome. Have you inspected the document with your browser to see? You're using more CSS than I'd think necessary for this fairly simple layout.

Comment: Your `logoDigipass1` is overlapping the input, catching any clicks intended to select that input.

Comment: The layout you posted does not need any absolute positioning or negative margins. I suggest you read up on how to use bootstrap and create the layout fully with bootstrap grid, then you don't have problems like this in the futue.

Comment: thank you for your replies, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested in the comments above, `logoDigipass1` is overlapping `section_instruction`.

To solve this problem add this to your CSS:

```
.section_instruction {
  position: relative; /* Add this */
  z-index: 1; /* Add this */
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
ol.wrapper_digipass {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

.title_digipass {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.information_digipass {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.instruction_digipass {
  list-style: circle;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.logoDigipass {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
  width: 130px;
}

.logoDigipass img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -31px;
  left: -12px;
}

.logoDigipass1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.logoDigipass1 img {
  height: 125px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.wrapper_digipass {
  position: relative;
}

.section_instruction {
  margin-top: -60px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative; /* Add this */
  z-index: 1; /* Add this */
}

.width30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.width42 {
  width: 42%;
}

.width434 {
  width: 434px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="section_digipass">
  <ol class="wrapper_digipass">
    <li class="title_digipass">Utilisez votre digipass.</li>
    <p class="information_digipass">Après avoir réactivé votre digipass et introduit votre code PIN, celui-ci demande quelle application vous souhaitez utiliser.</p>
    <ul class="instruction_digipass">
      <li>Appuyez sur le chiffre "2"</li>
      <li>Introduisez d'abord les 6 <u>chiffres</u> soulignés extraits du code SVM du titre <u>000347075</u> , qui sont <strong>007075</strong></li>
      <li>Introduisez le nombre de titres de l'opération, donc 10, suivant le format : <strong>000010</strong></li>
      <li>Le digipass vous fournit un code de 6 chiffres à introduire dans la zone de confirmation</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="title_digipass">Introduisez le code de 6 chiffres affichés par le digipass.</li>
    <div class="wrapper_digipass">
      <div class="logoDigipass1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </div>
      <div class="section_instruction">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-form-label text-end width42">
            <label for="code">Code de confirmation</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 width434">
            <input type="text " id="code" name="code" class="form-control d-inline width30 "> et cliquez ensuite sur <strong>"Confirmer ".</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```